# How to JOIN a table with a name that equals to a determined value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, select, subtypes

The model of the (PHP & MySQL based) Zend Framework 2 application I’m currently working on contains a inheritance similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35415323/2019043).

To map this to the database I’m using the [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) design pattern.

I’m cheating a bit and let the “super-entity” (i.e., the supertype) know, which type of “sub-entity” (i.e., the subtype) belongs to it. That means, the “super-entity” has a property (i.e., attribute or column) named `type`. The value is camel-cased (for an easier usage in the application). The table names are always underscored.

**Here is a diagram depicting my database structure**

[image: ERM/PDM]

**And a diagram displaying class models for my application program objects**

[image: class model]

The problem is now the retrieving. When I want to get a `Car` with `id=123`, I don't know at first, which `type` it has and hence which `car_*` table I have to `JOIN`. Well, I could workaround it, either `JOIN`ing  every time all `car_*` tables or making two request (when the first one is something like a “pre-request” and is used to get the `type`: `SELECT type FROM car;`), but I’m sure, there must be a better solution.

**How to `SELECT`/`JOIN` a `TABLE` with a variable name, that equals to a selected value in another `TABLE`?**

Comment: I don't think this is possible in any SQL RDBMS. You'll have to use two separate queries.

Comment: You mean my first workaround? Well it's not nice, but it would work. But only when I want to get _one_ result (`WHERE id = 123`). For result sets it's not even a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly without drawing in all the tables. You would need to first pick out the table name needed then use ad-hoc SQL or call a specific procedure per table to get the data out.

Drawing in all the tables as follows would work:

```
SELECT ac.carID, ac.type, ac.commonAttribute1, ac.commonAttribute2
     , ct.specialAttributeA
     , ca.specialAttributeB
     , cb.specialAttributeC
FROM   AbstactCar ac
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       CarTesla ct ON ct.carID = ac.CarID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       CarAstonMamn ca ON ca.carID = ac.CarID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       CarBMW cb ON cb.carID = ac.CarID
```

but obviously this is limited by needing to know all the types in advance and/or update the query every time a type is added/dropped/changed and possibly hitting some limit on the number of tables in any given `SELECT`. If a non-common attribute can appear in more than on of the sub-classes then change the definition for that output column to something like `ca.specialAttributeD, cb.specialAttributeD AS specialAttributeD`.

<sup>**NOTE:** I'm pretty sure the above is mysql compatible, but I'm generally an MS SQL Server fellow and haven't tested it so you may need to tweak the syntax slightly.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's a workaround and not a solution. But there also seems not to be a real solution in MySQL (at least for now). Anyway thanks again for trying to help!

Comment: @automatix well then, I would say that only "solution" would be to use a different schema which is more suited for a relational DB.

Comment: No, there isn't anything that mySQL and its descendants can do for you currently. PostgreSQL natively supports a form of table inheritance (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html) which, particularly when combined with partitioning, may do what you are looking for if you were able to use that instead of mySQL.